# Generic type with dynamic key

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

Given the following, the parameter `value` of the render method is typed as `string | number`.

How can I make sure that it gets typed as `T[dataIndex]`, which is `string` in case `dataIndex: 'name'`, and `number` in case `dataIndex: 'id'`?

```
import * as React from 'react'

type Col<T extends object, K extends keyof T> = {
    title: string;
    dataIndex: K;
    render: (value: T[K]) => React.ReactNode;
};

function Tab<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(list: T[], cols: Col<T, K>[]): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {cols.map(col => (
                        <th key={col.title}>{col.title}</th>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {list.map((item, i) => (
                    <tr key={i}>
                        {cols.map(col => (
                            <td key={col.title} children={col.render(item[col.dataIndex])} />
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}

Tab(
    [
        { id: 1, name: 'Hello' },
        { id: 2, name: 'World' }
    ],
    [
        {
            title: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            render: value => <span>{value.length}</span>
        },
        {
            title: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            render: value => <span>{value}</span>
        }
    ]
);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFA0wCeYWcAwhADYA8AKnFgA8YWAHYATdBABGAKyz4ANHADS-IaIlwA1lgYQCcHgD44AXjgBvGnBtwYwGBywAuOKhhRgIgOYBua7ZiyDDIAJLigq7K-rZwlBFQrgAUAG7IHACuLoYA2soAugCUZibYeDAAdGX4AHIQYlj%20AL7%20NAQZIvjAECKGyFK8asLikrLyMEqqgsOaOnoGfOZz%20oZGSRzA7q48OflKuJyoruzcPJNGu4WuAFIAygAaFQCiTiCi8FaxlDAZUL1JAViNi4ISkTiMgKBsRBAAscGIIVCkbYQVBEciMTYLAcOKgKiBkGAkjiSnAAZiKSiYDDtLpTNjOBV7I4sE0jAyOEyHE4mlwAPTU9GUqGFQpNSGU-keIUYqVw5AIiVIkFSeoMGWUiwbdz4wlJJIOLAgJTAYqmEzk4VQ1G0hj04BspVW2IcvEEokk81kp3O60wMS2%20k4rksppwXAw4AcMTxIOM%20INKAG4QgHLBoIhcINARFMN8jW%202yi8WFlECtE%205HFytlmCqsTqn1S-rgyGFZp0Hj9S02HI%20ixwYBiVwARiUImQb1cZAAElgOBwIGQ4E0FP3B8O4AAmceT7JkADq0Gjy5Ltj2kL7yM%20FOZTmnNT3ZDXlIzYQiAmnE7ez5rNgTWCJHAaSZCwXpcKgYDICI7IgVkFROD41K8nykHQQWNirv2f52Ny%206hGIv6vsE77ZtOQ5ERSAFAXBYEmBBUEwRYtEoWhME%20meNj5DQ7ZAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra type parameter to the component to capture the actual keys that are actually used as a tuple. You can then use a mapped type to map it to the array of columns, Typescript will be able to follow the reverse mapping and infer `K` from the array and then go back and correctly type the parameters.

```
type ColMapping<T extends object, K extends Record<number, keyof T>> = {
    [P in keyof K ]: Col<T, K[P] & keyof T>
}


function Tab<T extends object, K extends (keyof T)[]>(list: T[], cols: ColMapping<T, K>): JSX.Element {
//...
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFA0wCeYWcAwhADYA8AKnFgA8YWAHYATdBABGAKyz4ANHADS-IaIlwA1lgYQCcPgF5tu-YYB8cEwG8acB3BjAYHLAC44qGFGAiA5gDc9o5iyDDIAJLigp7KwY5wlDFQngAUAG7IHACuHoYA2soAugCU1lbYeDAAdFX4AHIQYljBAL7B9Ews7BwAsshgYH7+vGrC4pKy8jBKqoITmti40GJcIjkgUlhQSjp6BjwWVrYhDgUACnB+pgcqcMWevbxzl8VwAGS35kc0bXQ0Ag5ET4YAQESGZBSMYLDRTOSKe6wyZwNL7H6lArFCxpDjAbyeHhYpQrDioJ6cAZDEYvFQWUqeABSAGUABo1ACibhAongdkSlBgOSgELSZ0ScC4ESkbgs4sSUoAFjgxHKJeqJVKoGqNbrEjZSagaiBBmlSRVUfK9dalbcjAbODVnK4sG0LA6OE6XG42lwAPQwRU66260qlf4hzUB7VW9X+wMq4N6qVSZoMJORmx47zG01pFxYEBKYDlIxWMWR3Vau02YBu2OV-WG3NgM2cC0VxuVqViGukr0utpwXCK4AcMTJe395ItKD54QgAr9sIRaItARlId+jNdxJhiO7xzxmO7-cNhUB1NidMN+NQ2Xi0rtOg8KGd84NmzXMSeACMShEZAeU8MgAAksA4DgIDIOA2gUT9v08AAmACgPyMgAHVoHHGCDwcYp4MSAp+Q1Z03BAnhvSwMhCI1FcohiAQQMAnkaIbGcdk8LJchYMtJVQMBkBEd1uLyX0-QEoSkzgkj1TI9DIjENjdXotdYnIYAlNo9UONSOBRN4qwuEk4SbAM8STOk8VihoJ8gA)

Comment: I will update my example. In my case I have an array of Col, where each column has a different `dataIndex`.

Comment: Oh wait it seems to work actually. I thought that specifying the `K` on the `Tab` wouldn't make sens since various `dataIndex` can be passed in `cols`. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the back and forth Titian, but this doesn't work if I add multiple columns, since K will then be of type `string | number`. Any solution for that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MaximeLechevallier the initial question only had one column. An array is more difficult. Let me have a look

Comment: Yes, I should have been clearer from the beginning. Thanks for your help 

Comment: Note: Make sure to upgrade to the last version of TypeScript (v5.4.2 as of now), and tell VSCode to use it. Otherwise you keep on getting the same error with old versions (my VSCode was using v4.9.5)